# Can't use local image in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I'm unable to use local images and I'm really unsure why. I've installed url-loader and file-loader as well as trying to require the file.

HeaderNavigation.js ( The image I'm trying to use is in the same directory and is referenced as the Brand Image).

```
/**
 * Created by Hewlbern on 17-Jan-17.
 */
import React from 'react';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

//import NavLink from "./Navlink"

export default React.createClass ({
    render() {
        /* <img src={require('./Example.png')} /> */
       // var Replace = "http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/08421690-8191-4264-b479-ce42341e2389/be95b1c7-c95d-41c2-ae7d-1713e67462f3.jpg";
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <LinkContainer to ="/">
                                <img src = {require('./Example.png')}/>
                            </LinkContainer>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav bsStyle = "tabs" >
                            <LinkContainer to ="/Product">
                                <NavItem eventKey = "{1}" >
                                        Product
                                </NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to ="/About">
                                <NavItem eventKey = "{2}">
                                        About
                                </NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <NavDropdown id="nav-dropdown" title  ="More" eventKey = "{3}" pullRight>
                                <LinkContainer to ="/Background">
                                    <MenuItem eventKey = "{1}">
                                            Background
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </LinkContainer>
                                <LinkContainer to ="/Contact Us">
                                    <MenuItem eventKey = "{2}">
                                            Contact Us
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </LinkContainer>
                            </NavDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This is my webpack file.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DEV = path.resolve(__dirname, "dev");
var OUTPUT = path.resolve(__dirname, "output");

var config = {
    entry: DEV + "/App.js",
    output: {
        path: OUTPUT,
        filename: "myCode.js"
    },
module: {
    loaders: [
        // js
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['babel'],
            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
            include: DEV,
        },
        //    PNG
        {
            test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
        },

        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        },

        // CSS
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
        },
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Just make sure that your image size is less than 10kb

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: The error was 

DOMPropertyOperations.js:142 GET file:///C:/Users/Hewlbern/Desktop/Software%20Dev/LegalinkApp/dev/Assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: How do I use a image size that is larger than 10kb?

Comment: @WitVault Any idea brohemian?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Any idea on the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want load image with a `local relative URL` as you are doing. React project has a default `public` folder. You should put your `images` folder inside. It will work.

[image]

Comment: How to give path?

Comment: Simple and works. Thanks. I was trying to simply load one single image and those loader and webpack configuration methods are giving me headache. With this I can just do like `<img src="01.jpg"/>` and it works.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me

```
import Img from './Example.png'
```

then in your img tag

```
<img src = {Img} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, I'm using this config in my current project.

```
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
    }, {
      test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2',
    }, {
      test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream',
    }, {
      test: /\.otf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-otf',
    }, {
      test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'file',
    }, {
      test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml',
    }, {
      test: /\.png$/,
      loader: 'file?name=media/[name].[ext]',
    }, {
      test: /\.jpg$/,
      loader: 'file?name=media/[name].[ext]',
    }],
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @NguyenThanh - Could you explain how the code works please? For example, "&mimetype=application/font-woff'," What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems that you have not specfied the loader for font-icons type of files such as woff, ttf and many others.

Also make sure that you have `url-loader` and `file-loader` installed.

Use below loader in your webpack config file -

```
   {
            test    : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            loader  : 'file'
   },
```

Similarly for loading images you can use following loaders

```
  {
          test    : /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/,
          include : path.join(__dirname, 'img'),
          loader  : 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=images/[name].[ext]'
  }
```

Also if you use url loader such as this one

```
'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
```

it means that maximum file size which can be loaded via url is of 10kb and their mimetype( a way to recognize media file types) is svg image and you will receive the file as an http resource url.

If your file size is greater than `10 kb` then it will not be loaded by `url-loader` instead it will be loaded by `file-loader` and `file-loader` will serve the files as static assest.

Comment: With that loader, 'file', is that the same as file-loader? And I'm guessing SVG and XML are not going to load a PNG file? Thanks for the effort @witvault !!

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not loading the PNG file @WitVault

Comment: @Michael Yes you are right file means file-loader and about url loader I had given just an example. I had given example for loading font specific files.
I have updated the answer with image loaders as well. Basically you need to add diff - diff loaders for diff file types

Comment: Cheers! Thanks so much again

Comment: Got a error at compilation - Module Parse Failed: C://......\Example.png unexpected character '@' (1:0). May need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. :( @WitVault .

Comment: Gonna bail for now but i'll come back and keep trying to work this out in a bit. Cheers.

Comment: Just make sure that you have installed file-loader, url-loader as your dependency.