# A javascript file holding image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, ecmascript-6

I'm working on my own portfolio website and using react-bootstrap to design my react components. I'm trying to insert my image using Image component of react-bootstrap.

But, in their example code, the value of src attribute is `holder.js/200x200`. For example, this is how you use the Image component.

`<Image src='holder.js/200x200 rounded>`
How do you put an image in a js file ?I do not understand that part. Can anyone help me understand it? Thanks.

Comment: there are services that host these - its just some path magic - nothing in the js file has an image.

Comment: oh okay, thanks for clearing that. I was starting to doubt my javascript knowledge by thinking about having image in js file. Lol. So can you tell me what should I use instead of holder.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, their docs are a bit unclear.

They are utilizing [holder.js](http://holderjs.com/) library that provides this functionality. In the end `src` of their `<Image>` element is the same as on basic html `<image>`, so it has to be a path to the resource.

Comment: so can you show me that by writing that line? Because I tried this: ```<Image src='myPicture' rounded />``` and I imported this myPicture image and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to include an image that you keep in your source files?

Comment: You may need to change `<Image src='myPicture'` to `<Image src={myPicture}` (change the quotes to curly braces)

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want to do. I have an image folder in my src folder and my image is inside that image folder. I want to use that image in this Image component.

Comment: Then @Shmili Breuer gave you a working answer. Just import the image to your component `import myPicture from '../somepathtoyourpic/myPicture.jpg` and then pass it to the image element like `<Image src={myPicture} .../>` the bundler will translate that to a path for you

Comment: yes, I would do that when I use simple img tag. But, here I tried doing it that way but it didn't work.```<Image src={myPicture}  rounded/>``` doesn't give me rounded image and also, how do I specify dimensions of my image just as there are in their docs?

Comment: Your image needs to be kept in `public` folder, reffer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105573/cant-use-local-image-in-react-js

Comment: I moved it to public. Can you tell me the path with which I should import it? I used ```../../public/myImage.jpg``` but it showed an error.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer I'm using the Image component of react-bootstrap. I imported it using ```import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image' ```. Now I am trying to insert my image using this component but it is not working.